# How do I stub a callback function inside object parameter using sinon?

Tags: node.js, unit-testing, sinon

Working on project that uses a STOMP library called [stompit](https://github.com/gdaws/stompit). Had to make a change that adds the `onReceipt` callback which is provided via [options](https://gdaws.github.io/stompit/api/client/#clientsendheaders-options) parameter.

Basically the code looks like this:

```
       const promise = new Promise((resolve) => {
            const frame = client.send(headers, {onReceipt: () => {
                client.disconnect();
                resolve();
            }});
            frame.write('something');
            frame.end();
        });
```

I am having issues stubbing out `onReceipt` part. I have tried the following in my tests but it doesn't work:

```
        const fakeFrame = {
            write: sinon.stub(),
            end: sinon.stub()
        };

        const fakeClient = {
            send: sinon.stub().withArgs(sinon.match.any, {onReceipt: sinon.stub().yields()}).returns(fakeFrame),
            connect: sinon.stub(),
            disconnect: sinon.stub()
        };
```

Any ideas what I might be doing wrong? The project is using Sinon 8.0.4 btw.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So turns out I needed to use `callsFake` to fake the function from `sinon.stub()` to do the trick.

Basically I ended up with this:

```
        fakeClient = {
            send: sinon.stub().callsFake((headers, options) => {
                options.onReceipt();
                return fakeFrame;
             }),
            connect: sinon.stub(),
            disconnect: sinon.stub(),
        };
```